# Throws StackOverflow Exception when sorting a Gridview Column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I'm trying to do Sorting on a Column. When I do that, it throws 'StackOverflow' Exception

aspx Code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdItems" runat="server"  Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdItems_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="grdItems_Sorting">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#808080"/>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <pagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="Small" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actionItemId" HeaderText="Item Id" SortExpression="actionItemId" >
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="65px"/>
                        <FooterStyle Font-Size="12px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dueDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Due By" HtmlEncode="False" >
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="65px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
            <pagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub grdItems_Sorting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles grdItems.Sorting
        Dim sortExpression As String = e.SortExpression
        ViewState("SortExpression") = sortExpression

        If grdItems.SortDirection = WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending Then
            grdItems.Sort(sortExpression, WebControls.SortDirection.Descending)
        Else
            grdItems.Sort(sortExpression, WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Now, I know that, since I'm using Sort() inside the Sorting event handler, it's throwing me that exception. Is there any other way around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of call Sort (and hence the event firing again recursively) to just change the direction, just set `e.SortDirection` and allow the executing sort to proceed.

Comment: @TnTinMn But, if I do that, I won't be using sortExpression anymore. And the required column will not be sorted.